# Comment est reçue l'utilisation d'expressions régionales dans des travaux comme ceux du baccalauréat ?

Tags: régionalismes

Comment est reçue l'utilisation d'expressions régionales dans des travaux comme ceux du baccalauréat ou la rédaction d'un manuscrit ?  Dois-je les éviter, ou sont-elles considérées comme acceptables par les autorités ?

Comment: I'm sorry but for me that question is far to vague to be answered.

Comment: est-ce que l'on pourrait avoir des exemples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J'aurais tendance à conseiller de ne pas les utiliser, sauf à ce que leur emploi soit justifié par une particularité du sujet de l'examen.

En plus de cela, le langage écrit est généralement neutre, et les expressions régionales font le plus souvent partie du langage oral. Le risque à utiliser des expressions régionales est donc de dégrader le niveau de langage du document que l'on écrit.

Mais je crois ceci inversement proportionnel à la taille de la région: il est probable et il serait même culturellement normal qu'il y ait des différences entre le langage écrit de Québec et celui de la France, à niveau de langage égal. Mais pas entre le langage écrit de Marseille et celui de Lille.

Answer (score 3):

Sans plus de précisions sur le type ou l'origine des ces expressions régionales, on peut malgré tout dire que la plupart des expressions régionales sont plutôt connotées comme ressortant du langage familier, donc certainement à éviter lors d'épreuves écrites (sauf bien sur lors d'épreuves écrites en langue régionale ;) ) ou lors de rédaction de courrier officiel.